# Semantic Issue Qt Creator: no member named 'cout' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, qt-creator, semantics, clang++

I started to code with Qt Creator. For C++ files I get a lot of semantic issues.
99% are "no member named 'xxx' in namespace 'yyy'
The cpp files build, compile and output without a problem. If I click on e.g. cout I'm linked to iostream. Is there something I have to adjust in Qt so that Qt doesn't throw these semantic issues anymore?

Edit 18.09.20:
I found the problem, it's caused by ClangCodeModel-plugin, which was enabled. Does anyone know what problem qt has with Clang?

[image: error message hello world]

[image: compile output]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Qt Creator but VisualStudio is providing IntelliSense which is impertinently lieing sometimes (especially concerning "errors" which are effectively not there). Semantic analysis of C++ is not easy. That's why I bear with this. So, the only instance you really can trust is the compiler itself. In your case, it might be that the [Semantic HIghlighting](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtcreator-4.0/creator-highlighting.html) doesn't work properly. You could try to fix this or just disable it.

Comment: Does the compile output say anything else?

Comment: Bah. All these newfangled tools. Should just use `ed` like my pappy and his pappy afore him.

Comment: make sure that ur kit is set well or post details showing its entries.

Comment: As stated above I found a solution. Thank you all for your help!